# Jenkins make -j option per node

Tags: jenkins

I've successfully created a Jenkins setup with multiple build agents (nodes) for building on different operating systems.

Each of my build agents has different hardware capabilities (especially in terms of CPU cores available). I'm trying to figure out the preferred/recommended way of passing a per-node variable to the `make -j <variable>` stage of my build pipeline:

```
stage('Build [FreeBSD]') {
    steps {
        dir('build') {
            sh 'make -j8'
        }
    }
}
```

As I don't want to do this explicitly in each of my project's pipelines I figured that I can add an environment variable to the node configuration of each node and then use then environment variable inside the build step.

Is this the correct/recommended way of doing this or am I missing some obvious infrastructure put in place for exactly this?

I'm currently running Jenkins 2.267 and my pipelines are declarative.

Comment: If each node has a unique value it makes sense to keep those values coupled to their nodes. If you want to have all the values stored in one place you can define a `Map` with the node names as keys.

Comment: My question is exactly how to couple these values with the nodes. How would I go about that?

Comment: I meant to say that your proposal is correct. To add the environment variable select a node (from either the main page or from Manage Jenkins -> Manage Nodes) and click on Configure. Then in the Node Properties section tick the Environment Vairables checkbox and add the variable(s) you want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use *nix agents you can get the information from `/proc/cpuinfo`

```
// ...

dir('build') {
  sh "make -j\$(grep -c -E '^core id' /proc/cpuinfo)"
}

// ...
```

The more universal solution is using a groovy method that calls Java `Runtime.getRuntime().availableProcessors()`. Also, you need to approve your pipeline script [http://[jenkins-host]/scriptApproval](http://%5Bjenkins-host%5D/scriptApproval) page.

**Please note it may not safe in the security aspects. [Read here](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/managing/script-approval/)**

```
pipeline {
    
// ...
dir('build') {
  sh "make -j${cores()}"
}
// ...

}

def cores() { return Runtime.getRuntime().availableProcessors();}`
```